# Testing difference in mean with very large discrete sample set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, z-test

I am evaluating whether two thermometers are equivalent using a difference-in-mean hypothesis test. Both thermometers registered the daily maximum temperature over a few years, accurate to 1 decimal place. The two-tailed hypothesis test can be written as:

$\mathcal H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$

$\mathcal H_1: \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$

The null hypothesis is that the mean temperature ("population") measured by thermometer 1 and 2 are the same, and hence the thermometers can be considered equivalent. Conversely, the alternative hypothesis is that the thermometers produce different mean values, and are not equivalent.

My approach is to use a paired $t$-test, as both thermometers measured the same statistic (daily maximum temperature) and the two data sets are highly correlated. The results are summarized below, with mean and standard deviation values in $^\circ$C. The sample lengths are not the same as some measurements are missing.

[image][image]

(Note that $\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2\neq\bar{\Delta}$ as the difference series $\Delta$ is the difference between matched samples, both having a valid measurement for the same day.)

The $t$-statistic can be calculated as:
$$
T=\frac{|\bar{\Delta}|}{s_{\Delta}/\sqrt{n_{\Delta}}}=\frac{0.235}{0.386/\sqrt{1079}}\approx20
$$
with $DoF=1078$. Alternatively, the $z$-statistic can be calculated (assuming $s=\sigma$). Nevertheless, the $p$-value is very close to zero ($4.1\times10^{-76}$ depending on software implementation) using either $t$ or normal distributions. The null hypothesis would then be rejected under any significance level $\alpha$.

Because of the large sample size, the standard error is small, and hence the $t$-statistic large. It seems that this approach would favor $\mathcal H_1$ by design.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a better approach to evaluate the equivalence between the two thermometers?
2. Should the 0.1 $^\circ$C sample spacing be included in the evaluation? The distribution of the measured data (observed temperature series of each thermometer) has a wider support region, and can possibly be approximated as continuous. However, the distribution of the difference series is discrete, with difference values concentrated within [-0.5,0.3].

**More technical details:**

The daily maximum temperature measured over a few years is cyclical, but two equivalent thermometers should measure the same value every day. Below a few charts summarizing the situation, with a description of each.
[image]

a) Thermometer 1 is a RTD: [Resistance Temperature Detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer) - an electronic thermometer.
Thermometer 2 is a MiG: [Mercury-in-glass thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-in-glass_thermometer) - the classical instrument to measure maximum temperature.

The time series of each with corresponding 14-day moving average are shown. At this scale, the differences are not very clear - it does however seem that the MiG thermometer records slightly warmer overall.

b) The difference series between the two thermometers illustrate a seasonality - in warmer months (Southern Hemisphere) the differences are smaller.

c) The distributions of the two thermometers are nearly the same, however the MiG thermometer seems to have a slight shift to the right (i.e. slightly warmer). Months at the beginning and end of the record are removed to ensure only full seasonal cycles are included. This is to avoid skewing the distribution more than it really is.

d) The discrete histogram of the difference show the MiG thermometer to record slightly warmer. The histogram is discrete with sample spacing 0.1 $^\circ$C, as the temperature data is accurate to 1 decimal place.

e) The table provides the same values as above.

Initially I want to establish whether the measurements are statistically different overall (including seasonal effects), before evaluating each season in isolation.

Comment: First, plot the two time series. There could be some time drift, I would check that first. Can you share the plot with us?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I added more details with a few charts. Thank you.